# Multipart upload big files with Blazor c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor-server-side, owasp, blazor-webassembly

Is there anyone hehe who has experience with uploading very large files (3-5Gb) in Blazor and know if it works well, eg using c#, JavaScript manual shunk up files or HTML5 File API multipart upload? Preferably without a third-party library.

I also have a general question about the scenario of a logged in user if there are no special restrictions set for allowed file types possible to upload, what security concerns can still be handled using c#, JavaScript client, server side with regard to eg OWASP?

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in one post. Stick to a single focused question at a time. please take the Tour and read the How Do I Ask a Good Question guide in the Help area. The come back here and update this post. You're asking multiple questions and they are all to vague / broad

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have gotten it to work properly is to make a native call to an API that is running on the same server.

You can use fetch or ajax to do so.
An example on how to use fetch: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-upload-files-fetch

After it has been uploaded you can check the file location using dotnets file system.

You can always check the file extension however I would not recommend allowing just anyone to upload files to your website.

There is an API for virus total, I have not used it so look it through yourself!
https://github.com/Genbox/VirusTotalNet

You have to do it using pure javascript or jquery any attempt to do it using c# will use signalR and that has a very slow upload.